# How to pass parameters to partial in Comfortable Mexican Sofa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comfortable-mexican-sofa

How to pass parameters to partial in Comfortable Mexican Sofa. I have something like this:

```
module MySnippetHelper

  def my_partial
    # add something into array
  end

end
```

Partial:

```
 <% my_partial.each do |item| %>
     # some text to display
  <% end unless my_partial.empty? %>
```

And I call in my snippet in Comfortable Mexican Sofa:

```
{{ cms:partial:snippets/my_partial }}
```

How can I pass a value to the partial so it could print something like this:

```
 <% my_partial.each do |item| %>
     <%= # My variable that I have passed to the partial %>
  <% end unless my_partial.empty? %>
```

I get the display right, but I can't make it to display my custom variable to the partial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today, I am guessing, I will be answering to my own questions :)

The answer for this one is this:

Change:

```
{{ cms:partial:snippets/my_partial }}
```

To this:

```
{{ cms:partial:snippets/my_partial:"your value you want to pass in"}}
```

And then in partial you can use:

```
  <% my_partial.each do |item| %>
     <%= param_1 %>
  <% end unless my_partial.empty? %>
```

See documentation at https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Tags You can pass as many parameters as you want. I somehow missed that when I was first reading.